# Foundation 5 Off-canvas navigation animation time

Tags: zurb-foundation

Foundation 5 off-canvas animation works well but I just hope to modify the menu in-out time, and I haven't found anything related to this control. can anyone help me out? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Foundation 5 uses CSS transition rules to control the timing of the menu as it slides open and closed.

You can see in [foundation/scss/foundation/components/_offcanvas.scss](https://github.com/zurb/foundation/blob/master/scss/foundation/components/_offcanvas.scss), around line 60 (depending on which minor version of foundation you are using), the following:

```
// Transition Variables
$menu-slide: "transform 500ms ease" !default;
```

And later in the file, it's applied to the inner-wrap element:

```
// INNER WRAP
// Main content area that moves to reveal the off-canvas nav
@mixin inner-wrap {
  @extend %kill-flicker;
  @extend %wrap-base;
  @include clearfix;

  -webkit-transition: -webkit-#{$menu-slide};
  -moz-transition: -moz-#{$menu-slide};
  -ms-transition: -ms-#{$menu-slide};
  -o-transition: -o-#{$menu-slide};
  transition: #{$menu-slide};
}
```

So if you want to change the timing, you'd change that `500ms` to a different value.